# Converting Delphi code to Java

Tags: java, delphi, delphi-xe

I have a problem by converting the following piece of Delphi code to Java. 
The code I posted in here is just a small part of my full code that I took to describe my problem.

```
type
  TSecureArray = Array of AnsiChar;

const
  CodePosIdx = 10; 

function ReadLenFromArray(aArray:TSecureArray):integer;
var
  HS:integer;
begin
  Hs:=0;
  HS:=Hs+(ord(aArray[3]))*$1000000;
  HS:=Hs+(ord(aArray[4]))*$10000;
  HS:=Hs+(ord(aArray[5]))*$100;
  HS:=Hs+(ord(aArray[6]));
  result:=HS;
end;

function Decrypt(Source: Ansistring): Ansistring;    
var 
  srclen, aArrayLength: integer;
  aArray: TSecureArray;
  cryptedstring:AnsiString;
begin
  aArrayLength:=Length(Source); // length of source-String in my test case is 1046
for i:=1 to aArrayLength do                                      
    aArray[i]:=Source[i];

  srclen:=ReadLenFromArray(aArray);  // function returns 858862149 in my test case
  cryptedString:='';
  for i:=1 to srclen do
    cryptedstring:=cryptedstring+aArray[aArraylength-srclen-ord(aArray[CodePosIdx])+i];
end;
```

in Java I've implemented this piece of Delphi code as:

```
 protected static int readLenFromArray(char secureArray[])
    {
        int arrayLength = secureArray.length;
        int hs = 0;

        if(2<arrayLength)
        {
        hs = hs + (int) secureArray[2] * 0x1000000;
        }

        if(3<arrayLength)
        {
        hs = hs + (int) secureArray[3] * 0x10000;
        }

        if(4<arrayLength)
        {
        hs = hs + (int) secureArray[4] * 0x100;
        }

        if(5<arrayLength)
        {
        hs = hs + (int) secureArray[5];
        }

        return hs;


 }

    protected static String deCrypt(String code)
    {  
    int codePosIdx = 10;
    char [] secureArray;
    int srcLen;
    int arrayLength;

    arrayLength = source.length();   // 1046 in my test case

    for (i=0; i<arrayLength; i++)
    {
     secureArray[i] = source.charAt(i);
    }
    srcLen = readLenFromArray(secureArray); //  function returns 858862149 in my test case
    StringBuilder tmpStr = new StringBuilder();

    for(i=0; i<srcLen; i++)
    {
    tmpStr = tmpStr.append(secureArray[arrayLength - srcLen - 1 - (int) secureArray[codePosIdx - 1] + i]);
    }
    cryptCode = tmpStr.toString();

    return cryptCode;
    }
```

My problem is checking of condition in the for-Loop in Java. 
In my testcase `aArray[i + (int) secureArray[codePosIdx - 1]]` is equal to `aArray[-858861172]` and in contrast to Delphi it causes an `IndexOutOfBound` Exception. I avoided it in Java `readLineFromArray` function through if-statement. But how could I solve this problem in my `decrypt` function, so that the functionality of function is preserved for all values of parameters.
Any advice truly approciated!

Comment: present the full declaration of your Delphi function including full declaration of `TSecureArray` type. Same u do for `secureArray` in Java. Also tell your Delphi version. I suspect you stumbled upon `char/PChar/String` ambiguity. In some Delphi versions they are mapped to MBCS types `AnsiChar/PAnsiChar/AnsiString` but in other Delphi versions they are mapped to UTF-16 types `WideChar/PWideChar/UnicodeString` like text data probably is in Java.  Try to output and compare `sizeof(aArray[1])` in both Delphi and Java when you deal with unsafe bits-jockeying like `Ord`/`(int)`

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm using Embarcadero® Delphi® XE Version 15.0.3953.35171. TSecureArray is just my self-defined type. In Java I'm using a char array for that.  I'm totally new in Delphi and also not good familiar with Java. I have to convert a Delphi decryption algorithm to Java that I need to read the password from WindowsRegistry for my Java Client. There are another functions in code that I already implemented in Java and they're working well. 
The problem is the for-loop in Delphi from decrypt function that not work in Java.

Comment: It seems to me that the Delphi code was written for Delphi versions before Delphi 2009, when `Char` was `AnsiChar` and `string` was `AnsiString`. To use the Delphi code as a model for the Java code will lead to all kind of troubles along the way. Look for a specification of the functionality and code it in Java without even looking at the Delphi code.

Comment: @TomBrunberg The Delphi code was written 20 years ago. There is no more specification of it. Even my internship supervisor couldn't explain me how it work.

Comment: Ok, do you have e.g. D7 or D2007 to test with? How can you otherwise be sure that the Java code does what the Delphi code does? Is the return value from `ReadLenFronArray()` (858862149) reasonable? Anyway, as Johan wrote already, move away from string and char types. Cryptography does not operate on those types. BTW, of curiosity, is the Delphi code available on the net?

Comment: `The Delphi code was written 20 years ago` - which indeed suggests pre-Unicode Delphi

Personally i'd try to run the code in CodeTyphon/Lazarus which by default uses UTF-8 charset which matches plain ASCII/ANSIChar for first 128 chars of LATIN-1

Comment: can you show us few examples of DATA what strings should be passed into correctly working `Decrypt` function and what corresponding strings would be given as the result ?  // the lazy approach to us crypto over non-binary data made 20 years ago not came to backstab you... That sucks, but keep going.

Comment: sad to say but `I posted in here is just a small part of my full code` - it not just the "small part" - it is reduced so much that it is no more a real code and it can no more represent your original code... You removed absolutely critical parts of it. See my answer. All in all, crypto is absolutely sensitive to even minimal changes, so you have to present us with correct code and correct data samples... As long as you make incorrect reduction of code - that critically changes the behavior - hence we can no more reason about your real program behavior by those samples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the arrays in Delphi and Java you've declared are not the same.
You're using a `AnsiChar` in Delphi, which is one byte.
Java is always unicode and therefore the `char` type is two bytes.
You need to declare the Java array as `byte aArray[]`.

The second routine fails because the Java `String` is made up of two byte `chars` so that will never work.
Again you need to pass `byte aArray[]` and process that.

Because you are no longer working with strings, you cannot rely on the `.length()` function to get the length of the input, you'll either have to do your own test to see where the terminating zero byte is, or pass the length as a parameter.

Comment: since he uses Windows Registry to fetch the passwords ( I don't want to even talk how "secure" that is, my, my... ) I believe he does not have to worry about detecting string length - he gets it from registry via Win32 API, and that very API deals with MBCS/Unicode gap for applications...

Comment: I stumbled upon meaning and using of String and AnsiString, Array and AnsiArray in Delphi. For the Java implementation of Delphi code I just assumed it as String and Array without distinguishing whether they are one or two byte. 
If I use byte aArray[] in Java, does it mean that there will be no IndexOutOfBound Exception in the for-loop of readLineFromArray in my Java code?

Comment: In Delphi arrays are not objects(classes) but compiler intrinsics, low-level structures , unless you would explicitly ask compiler to check arrays boundaries - it would not do it saving few CPU commands on every array access. You need to explicitly ask for that extra safety if you need it - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Range_checking and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Compiling#Run.E2.80.91time_Errors_Options

Comment: @Johan There is in Delphi for each character of AnsiString 1 byte available, so that only ANSI can be used. Unlike Delphi byte is signed in Java. Have I also take it into account in my Java source code? Which encoding have I to use in this case when I convert byte [] back to string in Java. Is it right if I use UTF-8 like 
String bytesAsString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Answer (score 1):

Making this an answer for the sake of code formatting that I can not get in comments.

I guess I can se e a fundamental control flow problem in your functions, using the non-initialized ( that is: zero or random garbage ) data. Your function goes as that:

```
function Decrypt(Source: Ansistring): Ansistring;    
var 
  srclen, aArrayLength: integer;
  aArray: TSecureArray;
  cryptedstring:AnsiString;
begin
  aArrayLength:=Length(Source); // length of source-String in my test case is 1046
```

....and then suddenly...

```
  srclen:=ReadLenFromArray(aArray);  // function returns 858862149 in my test case
  for i:=1 to aArrayLength do                                      
    aArray[i]:=Source[i];
```

This is nuts!!! you did not initialized `aArray` nowhere, neither the container (length aka size aka volume) nor the data itself, yet you pass that nil=NULL pointer into `ReadLenFromArray` !!!

I think you wanted something like this:

```
function Decrypt(const Source: Ansistring): Ansistring;    
....
begin
  aArrayLength := Length(Source); 

  SetLength(aArray, aArrayLength); //  !!!!! init the container
  for i := 1 to aArrayLength do                                      
    aArray[i - 1] := Source[i];    //  !!!!! init the data in the container

  srclen := ReadLenFromArray(aArray); // now and only now can you use the array
   .....rest of function
```

You should note that for historical reasons ( which I do not think you are very interested in) strings in Delphi are indexed 1 to Length and dynamic arrays are indexed 0 to Length-1 - so i corrected indexes in the for-loop

As far as I can see you also forgot to initialize the `secureArray` in Java - you NEVER set its Length, so I can only wonder where the data falls to during assignments loop.

---

Basically your `ReadLengthFromArray` function just takes the slice of the array and (on Intel-endian machines) reverses byte order there.

More obvious and streamlined code would be like

```
function ReadLenFromArray(const aArray:TSecureArray): integer;
var
  HS : LongRec absolute Result;
begin
  if (High(aArray) < 6) or (Low(aArray) > 3) then 
     raise EAccessViolation.Create('The passed aArray does not have required data!');

  HS.Bytes[3] := ord(aArray[3]);
  HS.Bytes[2] := ord(aArray[4]);
  HS.Bytes[1] := ord(aArray[5]);
  HS.Bytes[0] := ord(aArray[6]);
end;
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.LongRec

Comment: I've composed the code in my question from the entire code and unfortunately put the initialization of array into wrong position in my piece of code. I edited it now. In the Java readLenFromArray function I'm just working with the array that was handed over as formal parameter for the function.

Comment: The index for the array initialization I took from the original Delphi source code and there is ('aArray[i] = source [i]').

Comment: what does your "original code" does with array length? does it set the length? or maybe that is the STATIC (fixed-boundaries) array there not DYNAMIC(variable-length) array? either there is a bad bug in the original code or in your misrepresentation of it in the sample. we need FULL declaration of aArray from the original code to be able to reason about it

Comment: you still did not initialized your array before copying data form string into it  - you just stuff the data into Win32 zero-page in Delphi which may result either in AV or into hidden memory corruption

Comment: So you posted fake code and want us to help! Do you think we enjoy doing that? Why are you so dismissive of our time? Stop being lazy. Think harder. Try harder. Spend more time. Check your work before posting. Make sure that the code you post is correct. Read this: [mcve].

Comment: @Arioch'The I declared TSecureArray as an array of char on the top of code and then declared my aArray in the decrypt function as TSecureArray and initialized with characters from source string. Anyway I don't need to improve the delphi code, because it's just a part of big programm and it's working well. I must to implement it in Java. As I said above my password is stored in Windows Registry and it's from type REG_BINARY and it has about there 1000 characters. After decrypting there must be as result just one character.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I actually read this article and that's why I didn't post the full code in here. My internship supervisor said also that I was very bad idea to post the full code in my previous deleted question. I took the relevant information for my question to make it 
understandable and I didn't think that is required to compile this piece of code to answer my question. This is the first time when I have to work and to programm alone. I'm trying to be better and your previous advises also helped me much.

Comment: It looks like you did not read the MCVE article carefully enough. Try reading it again. The M stands for minimal. You don't post your full code. You create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. Posting fake code as you did here does not help. I know this is probably bewildering to you but learning how to present and solve problems is really what matters to you.